# How do I set the positions of several game objects to DIFFERENT random positions with C#? (Unity5.5)

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I have this code to set random x and z coordinates for several game objects:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class SetPositions : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        int a = rnd.Next (-9,9);
        int b = rnd.Next(-9,9);
        transform.position = new Vector3(a, transform.position.y, b);
    }
}
```

When I use this script with multiple game objects, mot of them end up in the exact same location. I have gathered that this has something to do with the time being used, but how to I make sure all of the objects are in different positions? Is there a workaround to generate the random numbers at different times, or should the code be moved around/changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: You should never really need to use `System.Random` in Unity, use `UnityEngine.Random` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Scott Chamberlain's comment, I was able to find the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) for random numbers and solve my problem. UnityEngine.Random evidently does not use the time and so random positions are different from each other. Here is the correct script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SetPositions : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject PickUp;

    void Start() 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.5f, 9.5f), 0.5f, Random.Range(-9.5f, 9.5f));
    }
}
```

PickUp is a prefab that I use for all of the pickup objects.

Answer (score 1):

You may need [Random.insideUnitCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html)

```
var rndPoint = (Random.insideUnitCircle * 9);
transform.position = new Vector3(rndPoint.x, transform.position.y, rndPoint.y);
```

Or [Random.insideUnitSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html)

```
var rndPoint = (Random.insideUnitSphere * 9);
rndPoint.y = transform.position.y;
transform.position = rndPoint;
```

Comment: Where would I put that code in the context of my script?